# How to select destination for output AngularJS/Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I have an application built with AngularJS and node.js that takes in a csv file, does some work on it and then outputs it.

Currently the only way I can output it is:
`<a download="fileName.csv" ng-href="{{file}}">fileName.csv</a>"`

But this will always put it in the 'Downloads' folder. Is there a way to ask for the destination and use that to output the file?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There's no way to pick where the file ends up on the client machine, that's determined by their browser. It's going to your downloads folder because that's the default location.